# VAR Impulse response with a dummy variable

Tags: vector-autoregression

I have a var model :

y=dummy + other variables 
where dummy =1 if the firm is having a negative return on stock and 0 otherwise. Y is the return on stock. Is it appropriate to use the VAR model to study the impact of the dummy on y and other variables in this context?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at threshold VARs (TVAR). [Lo and Zivot, 2001](https://econpapers.repec.org/article/cupmacdyn/v_3a5_3ay_3a2001_3ai_3a04_3ap_3a533-576_5f02.htm) They allow you to estimate seperate Var equations depending on the state of the economy/firm. [image: Example][source](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~lkilian/SVARch18.pdf)

Here is variable c the threshold variable. In principle, an infinite number of boundaries are conceivable. In practice, however, it is usually no more than 2-3, which is also due to the limited number of degrees of freedom.

There are also TVEC Models, which can deal with cointegrated data.

Comment: This is a little brief as an answer by our standards; you could improve it by saying a little about what TVARs are and why you think they would help in this case.